# Add items to array in object

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of checkboxes that represent filters, so when clicking a checkbox it should add an object containing the type of filter (taxonomy) and the value (terms) to a filter array.

When clicking the checkbox it first adds a new object containing a taxonomy and terms property. So far this works. The problem is when i click a third checkbox that has an taxonomy value that already exists, it adds a whole new object to the array instead of adding the term to the already existing term array.

This is what it looks like right now:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="term-1" value="term-1" name="taxonomy-1">
<label for="term-1">Term 1</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="term-2" value="term-2" name="taxonomy-1">
<label for="term-2">Term 2</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="term-3" value="term-3" name="taxonomy-1">
<label for="term-3">Term 3</label>
```

File1.js

```
import FilterModule from '../helpers/filter-module';

class View {
    constructor() {
        self.filterModule = new FilterModule();
        this.$filters = $( '[data-filters]' );
    }
    
    // Called after api got data
    update() {
        // Set event listener for select(s)
        this.$filters.find( 'select' ).on( 'change', this.handleFiltering );
        this.$filters.find( 'input[type="checkbox"]' ).on( 'change', this.handleFiltering );
    }

    handleFiltering() {
        let tax = $( this ).attr( 'name' );
        const term = $( this ).val();
        self.filterModule.handleCheckbox( $( this ), tax, term );
    }
}

export default new View();
```

File2.js

```
import Api from '../helpers/api';

export default class FilterModule {
    handleCheckbox( checkbox, tax, term ) {
        const filters = Api.response.filters.active_filters;

        if ( $( checkbox ).is( ':checked' ) ) {

            // Check if taxonomy exists, if not, add it
            const index = filters.findIndex( x => x.taxonomy === tax );
            if ( index === -1 ) {
                console.log( 'does not exist, add new taxonomy object' );

                // Add new selection
                filters.push( {
                    taxonomy: tax,
                    terms: [ term ]
                } );
            } else {
                console.log( 'tax exists, push new term into it' );
                filters.find( x => x.taxonomy === tax ).terms.push( term );
            }

            console.log( filters );

        }

        // Update data
        this.update();
    }

    update() {
        Api.fetch();
    }
}
```

So the first checkboxes click works well, the result would be:

```
{
   taxonomy: 'taxonomy-1',
   terms: [ 'term-1' ]
}
```

Second click:

```
{
   taxonomy: 'taxonomy-1',
   terms: [ 'term-1', 'term-2' ]
}
```

But the third click results in:

```
{
   taxonomy: 'taxonomy-1',
   terms: [ 'term-1', 'term-2' ]
},
{
   taxonomy: 'taxonomy-1',
   terms: [ 'term-3' ]
},
```

I don't understand why a new object is added instead of pushing it to the terms array of the taxonomy that exists.

Comment: Can you provide enough context to reproduce the issue? (HTML? the way the function is called?)

Comment: How does `handleCheckbox` get called? When you say "third click", do you mean it always happens no matter which checkbox is clicked as third, or is it the same checkbox each time?

Comment: I've added some (simplified) more code. @RoToRa this happens on the same checkbox

Comment: In `handleFiltering` you are reading the taxonomy from the `id`, but in the HTML it's in the `name`. Due to in the incomplete code it's a bit difficult to determine what `this` is. A complete working snippet would make the debugging easier. Inside the event handler it probably be a good idea to use `target` from the event object instead of `this`.

Comment: Yes sorry, i updated my question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a workable example of your code, but changed the `let tax = $(this).attr('id')` to `let tax = $(this).attr('name');`.

So far, everything works as you expect, terms are added to the existing object instead of a new object being created:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', this.handleFiltering);

const activeFilters = [];

function handleFiltering() {
    let tax = $(this).attr('name');
    const term = $(this).val();

    handleCheckbox($(this), tax, term);
}


function handleCheckbox(checkbox, tax, term) {

    // activeFilters represents an array
    if ($(checkbox).is(':checked')) {

        // Check if taxonomy exists, if not, add it
        const index = activeFilters.findIndex(x => x.taxonomy === tax);
        if (index === -1) {
            console.log('does not exist, add new object');

            // Add new selection
            activeFilters.push({
                taxonomy: tax,
                terms: [term]
            });
        } else {
            console.log('tax exists, push new term into it');
            activeFilters.find(x => x.taxonomy === tax).terms.push(term);
        }

    }
    
    output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(activeFilters, null, 2);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="term-1" value="term-1" name="taxonomy-1">
<label for="term-1">Term 1</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="term-2" value="term-2" name="taxonomy-1">
<label for="term-2">Term 2</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="term-3" value="term-3" name="taxonomy-1">
<label for="term-3">Term 3</label>

<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks. My code seemed to work all along, the problem was the API not returning the data correctly!